# Xamarin - How do I use a list in outside its class

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've been trying to use my list from my PageCreator class outside its own class, this class is called MainCPage, this page is still in the same package. Whenever I type **PageCreator.** in my public MainCPage method it shows **PageCreator.pages**, But I can't seem to use it when I need it! Here is my code from both classes:

PageCreator.cs

```
public static List<ContentPage> pages = new List<ContentPage> (0);
    private string[] subjects = { "Welkom", "Bedrijfsgegevens", "Doelen", "Sales Funnel", "Sales Kit" };

    public PageCreator ()
    {
        StartPage ();
        BedrijfsGegevens ();
    }

    public void StartPage() {
        pages.Add (new ContentPage { Content = new StackLayout {
                BackgroundColor = "Black",
                Opacity = "0.75",
                Children = {
                    new Label { 
                        Text = subjects [0], 
                        FontSize = "40", 
                        HorizontalOptions = "Center", 
                        VerticalOptions = "Start" },
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Het Commerciele Huis uit Aalten (Achterhoek) is een instituut op het gebied van optimalisatie van commercie en communicatie. " +
                        "Wij werken met passie aan uw resultaat.",
                        FontSize = "26",
                        WidthRequest = "300",
                        HorizontalOptions = "Center",
                        VerticalOptions = "Center"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

MainCPage.cs

```
    public class MainCPage
{
    public MainCPage ()
    {
        PageCreator ();

        MainCPage = new CarouselPage {
            Children = {
                /*this is where I want to add the pages from the list
                  But it PageCreator.pages doesn't show up*/
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me what I`m doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
It was IntelliSense that wasn't working when I tried to type PageCreator inside Children. The following code should and must work:

```
MainPage = new CarouselPage {
    Children = { PageCreator.pages [0],
                 PageCreator.pages [1]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that won't work. The initializer syntax you are using for Children is equivalent to `Children.Add(page)`. `Add` does not accept a collection of pages. Instead, you'll have to list out each page in there.

I've also noticed that IntelliSense does not always work inside that initializer. I'm running Xamarin Studio 6.0 and it is working, so I am thinking it's fixed in the Alpha Channel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it was indeed intellisense which wasn't doing its job. Thanks man!